# Присвоение значений директиве @model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Почему я не могу присвоить значение объявленной директиве @model напрямую без использования хелперов, вот так

```
@model site.Models.PageNews
Controllers.NewsController dataControllerNews = new Controllers.NewsController(); 
Model.MenuNews = dataControllerNews.OneUpdateMenuNews(new Models.MenuPanelNews());
```

выдает ошибку

> System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

**Или как то все таки можно.**

Answer (score 4):

Вы пытаетесь присвоить значение свойству объекта модели, который ещё не инициализирован.
Естественно получаете исключение.

По хорошему, значение для `Model` должно присваиваться в контроллере на сервере. После чего страница рендерится и отправляется в браузер.

То, что делаете Вы (создание контроллера и получение модели в представлении), как минимум нарушает принцип MVC. Каждый компонент этого паттерна должен заниматься своим делом.

Comment: Хорошо у меня следующий вопрос, если я создаю глобальную директиву @model с определенным типом данных и у меня есть две Html.BeginForm на странице, то при отправки данных в методы на сервер, В ГЛОБАЛЬНУЮ ДИРЕКТИВУ считываются и отправляются только данные находящиеся в обрабатываемой форме а параметры внесенные из другой формы в эту же директиву НЕТ, это можно решить или придется все лепить в одну Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам проводить все эти операции прямо в модели?

Решение 1:
Заполнить это свойство прямо в контроллере на этапе формирования модели.

Решение 2:
Передавать объект в ViewBag или ViewData. И использовать его на странице

```
var menuNews = ViewBag.MenuNews as MenuPanelNews;
var menuNews = ViewData["MenuNews"] as MenuPanelNews;
```

Решение 3:
Напишите метод, но не в контроллере, а в пространстве Helpers, учитесь разделять логику.

```
@model site.Models.PageNews
@{
   var menuNews = site.Helpers.Class1.OneUpdateMenuNews(new Models.MenuPanelNews());
}
```

Где Class1

```
namespace site.Helpers
{
   public static class Class1
   {
      public static MenuNews OneUpdateMenuNews(MenuPanelNews menuPanelNews)
      {
         //TODO
      }
   }
}
```